# Visual Studio vs Visual Studio Code for ReactJS development

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs

Has anyone compared Visual Studio (2015/2017) vs Visual Studio Code for ReactJS development?  I'm starting on a new project soon and was wondering what is everyone's view/preference when it comes to editor? Any pros/cons?

Comment: I can't say anything about Visual Studio, but VS Code is a bliss to use for JS development. I don't think I'd trade it for a heavier IDE like visual studio